# Eclipse finds wrong GCC (Windows)

Tags: c++, windows, eclipse, gcc, mingw

Just installed Eclipse on Windows and I'm trying to create a project. I want to create a simple plain project with MinGW compiler toolchain. I can, but I couldn't figure out how to specify which MinGW to use, and now it wants to use the MinGW bundled with the Haskell Platform which is quite old.

Is there a way to specify the directory of MinGW to use? (I want to use the MinGW from [nuwen.net](http://nuwen.net/mingw.html), that is the default `g++` command in the path)

Comment: Eclipse? MinGW? Why not make your life easier, download [Visual Studio Express 2013 for Windows Desktop](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/downloads#d-express-windows-desktop) and start writing code.

Comment: @IInspectable: Although I wouldn't use Eclipse for my IDE, using MinGW makes sense. First, it claims to have the best C++11 support at the moment, and second, it provides a good way to test your code for gcc compatibility. Because it IS possible to write a code that will compile on MSVC but not on GCC. Anyway, you really shouldn't criticize tools other people use. I mean, at least in this case his compiler is not Turbo C.

Comment: @SigTerm And you can write code that will compile on GCC but not on MSC. MinGW might not be a bad tool. Eclipse, however, is. It was a comment to draw attention to a fuss-free toolset. And an IDE that can easily integrate with MinGW (using a MAKEFILE project type, for example).

Answer (score 0):

If you can find the desired compiler from the command line, then the easiest way is simply
1) add compiler to to the path 2) start Eclipse from the same command line.

For example, to use Visual Studio as a compiler I start Eclipse from Visual Studio command prompt. You probably need to start Eclipse from proper cygwin command prompt.